# Handling event on click of a browser item?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-like

I have to do  facebook like onclicking of a button in ViewControler . It should like our page on the back end automatically as we see in many website.

I didn't find a better solution but still i open my facebook page onclick. and the user can manually like the page in the browser. Now i want to handle whether user like that page or not in browser.

**Simple Words**

When user like my page i have to save it in my database whether he likes my page or not. I open my `facebook page` on button click . It opens in a `webview or browser`, User may not like my page and press back button how could i know whether he likes my page by enabling Javascript or check some other way that the button is clicked or not.

**It would be very helpful if someone told me how to directly like our page automatically onclicking of a button in IOS.**

I know `WebView delegate:` shouldStartLoadWithRequest

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{


    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked){

        NSURL *url = request.URL;
        [self openExternalURL:url];//Handle External URL here

    }

    return YES;

}
```

but there are multiple button how to distinguish between those button. or i mean how i know that like button is clicked..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: [Facebook like](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes)

You need to have publish_actions permissions. The graph url for this is: https://graph.facebook.com/[User FB ID]/og.likes?object=OG_OBJECT_URL&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

However, you cannot use this to like a page on Facebook currently, as the documentation states:

> For Facebook Pages or websites that do not integrate with Facebook
>   Authentication, developers should continue to use the Like button
>   social plugin.